# Save As... on Mac always saves in "Library/Autosave Information"

Tags: mac, osx-lion, xcode

I'm incredibly frustrated with my Mac right now. Every time I try to re-save any file that I recently opened, it doesn't overwrite the file I opened, it instead saves to a duplicate copy that is stored in "Users/Wex/Library/Autosave Information". For every file that I try to save, I have to do Save As..., then select the correct file in the correct directory. How can I fix this? This problem started after I began using XCode 4. I am running Lion on my Mac.